# How to iterate ArrayVector in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, grafana

I am developing a grafana plugin. I get the data in ArrayVector. i.e.

[image: Array Vector Data]

I have to iterate/print each value of buffer. Currently my code is:

```
console.log("props : " , this.props.data.series[0].fields[0].values);
```

This code gives me the array code as shown in above image. How can i access each value of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can access in this way

```
var result = this.props.data.series[0].fields[0].values['buffer'].map( buff=> {
   return {
    value: buff,
   } 
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: values does not show buffer property when i press dot after values. values is not an array, it is an ArrayVector @techguru

Comment: okay as mentioned in question , the ArrayVector is an array? am i ri8?

Comment: I think array and arrayVector are different

Comment: `console.log(typeof(this.props.data.series[0].fields[0].values))`, can you check once? i have updated the answer, please check once

Comment: no, there is difference between Array and ArrayVector. You codes will work with Array but not with ArrayVector @techguru . . . . I have added the answer which resolved my issue, you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the things working with the help of `toArray` method and `foreach` loop. Code is:

```
this.props.data.series[0].fields[0].values.toArray().forEach(function(entry){
  console.log("Value from buffer : " , entry)
});
```